# How to optimize my Neural Network?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am new to neural networks, and watching lots of toturials manged to build my first one, but something is not right.

The input consists of 100 inputs, all numbers between 0 and 100.
The output has three classes [x,y,z], where only one of them could be 1, and the others should be 0, so there is only 3 outcomes
[1,0,0], [0,1,0] and [0,0,1]

I am experimenting with the following setup

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(100,), activation='sigmoid'),
    Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'),
    Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')
    ])

model.compile(Adam(lr=0.0001),loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(bets, results, validation_split= 0.20, batch_size=10, epochs=200, shuffle=True, verbose=3)
```

The problem I am getting is that the output is not total to 1, so ideally I should be looking at

for example [0.1, 0.3, 0.6] or [0.7, 0.2, 0.1] or [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]

But when I run prediction, I am getting something like

for example [0.8, 0.2, 0.9]

Maybe the model needs to be trained for longer than 200 epochs, but not sure if my other configurations are correct for the values of my input and output.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically if you want your output to sum to 1 you add a softmax layer as the last layer in your neural net, which outputs a sort of pseudo-probability measure.

This should work:

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(100,), activation='sigmoid'),
    Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.0001),loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(bets, results, validation_split= 0.20, batch_size=10, epochs=200, shuffle=True, verbose=3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That kind of worked, but the output is now not helpful either, it seems as it is the same ration of the previous results, but they sum to 1, example [0.45, 0.05, 0.5]. Looks like needs more training

Comment: Dear Mocas, according to your initial question the issue "is that the output is not total to 1". I believe Bwood94's answer is correct to that regard. If you want better prediction results I would recommend you to test different parameters (for example using RELU instead of 'sigmoid' for your second layer. But it's hard to know what would work without looking at the data. Others structures of networks may improve the prediction as well.

Answer (score -1):

A neural network, in normal conditions, will never give you a sum of possibilities, which means `P(a)` is not equal to `1-P(b)` in case of two outcomes. Instead, it gives you an approximated value close to that one after enough training, depending on the weighting function.

Now, looking at your code, you probably train our NN with wrong logic. `[0.8, 0.2, 0.9]` looks like `[1, 0 ,1]` which is complementary of one of your desired outputs `[0, 1 ,0]`.

Print all your outputs to see if this is the case, then act accordingly to shift the output.

And one last thing: with your desired outputs, NN will give you something like `[0.06, 0.93, 0.15]`, two are close to `0`, and the other close to `1`. The values shall not sum to 1, if they are, then you are doing something wrong.